# Encode the simple substitution cipher

Tags: code-golf, cipher

**Review**

First, let's review the Simple Substitution Cipher.

To encode a string in the Simple Substitution Cipher, replace each letter in your string with another letter.

A letter may not be used to replace more than one existing letter.

For example, if I was encoding the text `Hello world, my name is Oliver! I like code golf!` with the key `zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba` (`a -> z, b -> y, etc.`) then the encoded text would be `Svool dliow, nb mznv rh Lorevi! R orpv xlwv tlou!`.

**Your task**

Your task is to encode the simple substitution cipher. Given a string of decoded text and a key, output the encoded text.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest number of bytes wins.

Comment: *Given a string of encoded text and a key, output the encoded text*. There should be a **decoded** in there shouldn't it?

Comment: reopened this as per our policy of closing older answers as dupes of older questions.

Comment: A little more details would be nice. In your example, you encode uppercase letters that do not appear in your key, yet no such thing is mentioned in the spec.

Comment: This is essentially "Implement UNIX `tr`", and just parameterises an existing `tr` question.