# Encrypt this Message

Tags: code-golf, string, encryption

Given a permutation of the alphabet and an input string, encrypt the input string by replacing all characters with the one's you've been given.
The capitalization should be kept the same and non-letters are not to be changed.

```
[hnvwyajzpuetroifqkxmblgcsd], "Hello, World!" -> "Zytti, Giktw!"
```

As `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` has been mapped to `[hnvwyajzpuetroifqkxmblgcsd]`

### IO

Input may be taken in any reasonable form, output can either be to `STDOUT` or as a String.

### More test cases:

```
[ghrbufspqklwezvitmnjcdyaox], "Foo"                -> "Fvv"
[ubjvhketxrfigzpwcalmoqysdn], "123Test String :D"  -> "123Mhlm Lmaxze :V"
[qscxudkgemwrtbvnzolhyfaipj], "AAbcdeFghijK"       -> "QQscxuDkgemW"
```

Standard ruleset applies!

Comment: You should mention in the specs that caps should be encoded the same way as lowercase characters.

Comment: Is the input alphabet always in lowercase?

Comment: This needs some clarification. Will the input always be lowercase? You should mention that uppercase letters are mapped the same way as the lowercase letters. It's implied that non letter characters are untouched, but should be explicitly said so

Comment: This challenge appears to be a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98301, which is itself closed as a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22704.

Comment: @Dingus I'd close as a dupe of Encode the simple substitution cipher, but you can't do that since it's closed itself, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it's really a dupe of DVORAK Keyboard layout, since that's a subset of this challenge, and I don't think most answers can be trivially ported from that.

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77899. I would've closed it as a dupe of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98301, but can't (as it doesn't have any upvoted/accepted answers), so that should be considered the "true" dupe target.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing : agree with “user”’s comment above: the dvorak question is *not* a dupe. We could close this for being unclear, but that could be remediated. In my opinion, we *don’t* have a straight substitution encoding challenge here on codegolf. So in that sense, it’s a good challenge! We should encourage the OP to use the sandbox and then resubmit!

Comment: Am I just supposed to wait or is there anything I should do now?

Comment: @agtoever I haven't closed either this or the Dvorak question as dupes of each other. Potentially, it might be worth reopening this and closing all substitution cipher questions as duplicates of this, but that should be discussed on meta. As it stands, this challenge has already been done before, so I closed it as a duplicate of the earlier challenges. Additionally, the Sandbox wouldn't help at this point, it only works for dupe checking *before* posting

Comment: I guess that'd make sense. Especially since the only question that I would consider this is a duplicate of, has (in my opinion) falsely been closed and also doesn't have *any* answers. So IMO reopening this would be the best option.

Comment: In the last test case (`[qscxudkgemwrtbvnzolhyfaipj], "AAbcdeFghijK"       -> "QQscxuDkgemw"`), the final `w` in the solution should be capitalised (`"QQscxuDkgemW"`).

Comment: Fixed; Thanks a lot. On this note, I'd still be in favor of reopening this as the question this was marked a duplicate of, has falsely been flagged as a duplicate too and as such didn't recieve any answers.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

Expects `(permutation_string)(string)`.

```javascript
p=>s=>(B=Buffer)(s).map(c=>(B(p)[q=c&32,c-q-65]||c)&95|q)+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5dS8MwGAXge39FloutwX3gxgQHHWyMKagXQ1FQvEjTpE2bNmmSph/sv9d1CIo7l@flPLwJdtgQzZWd5DKkHfM75a@Nv/a2/rZkjGrkGTTNsPJIX3oKfRY@GS7mYzIpJrfLr@ORoOHd8lig69GoIzI3UtCpkJHHPBjnrmpw0qqSWi05K9I6C0RETAiRBx@oEHIM3qUW4QCCUxACsxmAH421fAzueWqrAbz6h0axDkpmVJGKiraO2yxPSNhgWffoXsoz9ZsfdO/cBVUGiYtTamvNeNSqimCRyaIxYd5TN/PFKzUWvFjN8wisdvCHOh2eY5GBpwzXLQWrtwu4MKQuwzSiWaVt4PJWirhhmKukhzebgIR0H8U8eYR/fzwc@t3uvIPdNw)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

Assuming using lists of ASCII codes is acceptable:

```javascript
p=>s=>s.map(c=>(p[q=c&32,c-q-65]||c)&95|q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdHfS8MwEAfw9/0VZx9GC12HjgkqHYzNKagPQ1Gw9CFN0zZt2qRJ1l/sf5/tVvHNLyEvd/fh4FJUIYUlFXpW8JCcIvck3JXqn5MjYWJ3ZQqvdPF0cWPjWTm7XfrHI7amd8tjaZ0evAmAB0ZSVHWL0k4ciJacRmXW5AGLsQoNG4xnwhi34YtLFl4ZMMS3YT4H47vVmtrwRDNdXxkXK05kcIiUKDNWk66iOi9SHLaIN4O14/wi/GW0dlU1CocgrZKM6EZGNO5EjRHLedmqsBiE65vFB1Ea3rWkRQz3W@NX6CtvCcvhNUdNR@D@c/RKhZtDmMUkr6UOqqLjLGkjREU6eOt1gEOyixOavoyr@XD29vthcHseNCb@xIm4fEQ4MU1P2KB8C9wVYF4ozojDeGxeVnIiyfNNguSmP4jpOE5kev0v/MtFzkMOHutrbVqWdW5Q/zT0Of0A)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
DuìD{s‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fpfTwGpfq4kcNC///L03KKsvITi2pKErLTK8qKE9OzMnNL6wsTsnjMjQyDkktLlEILinKzEtXsHIBAA)

```python
Du       # make a copy of the permutation and convert it to uppercase
  ì      # prepend the uppercase copy to the permutation
   D{    # make a copy of the new string and sort it
         # this always creates 'A ... Za ... z'
     s   # swap alphabet and permutation
      ‡  # transliterate the second input based on the given strings
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
Œu;$ØẠ,y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY67DoIwAEV/BRtHFnXTicQYE0dNjCN90AelhT6A8hlOjm7@gyvxQ/ySaqeT3HOHI4iUIcbP3e@W8@P7fuYhzi9wixEw1Q@hFFPriTOaV109NlBSZDHIM0CZgb6ybVfLgUw9d40SCIdSj8l6KHpWEzeaitOpHVApG90Fi1WynUWjxzUlzWAc7NWkJQtVyVsBIjj@i3SeXbWReJHeB60TVuvNhViXnZ3himbbfRqLAiJMDpRxcQI/)

Chaining rules make this too long.

### How it works

```
Œu;$ØẠ,y - Main link. Takes permutation P on the left, string S on the right
   $     - Last two links as a monad f(P):
Œu       -   Uppercase P
  ;      -   Prepend that to P
    ØẠ   - Alphabet; Yield "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      ,  - Pair; [ØẠ, P ; upper(P)]
       y - Transliterate S, according to that mapping
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
:⇧+kL$Ŀ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3A%E2%87%A7%2BkL%24%C4%BF&inputs=hnvwyajzpuetroifqkxmblgcsd%0AHello%2C%20World!&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
:⇧+kL$Ŀ
:⇧+      # append the uppercase version of the input to the input
   kL    # push a-zA-Z
     $   # swap those
      Ŀ  # and transĿiterate the message
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 18 bytes

```
tr a-zA-Z $1${1:u}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhabSooUEnWrHHWjFFQMVaoNrUprIRJQ-X3RShl5ZeWViVlVBaWpJUX5mWmF2RW5STnpycUpSrFrPVJzcvJ1FMLzi3JSFCFaAA)

Trivial.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>25</s> 21bytes

```apl
{(×⍵)×⍺∘(,⊃⍨⎕A⍳⊢)¨⌈⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTflfrXF4@qPerZogctejjhnVGkBaByQS/ahvquOj3s1AdmztoRWPejqArFouLBrg6jQfdTVDtSN0YFihoQNWtgKmr2uRJkKxs8KjtgkKQJ56Rl5ZeWViVlVBaWpJUX5mWmF2RW5STnpycYo6VzBYlbpHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqiOhfQQLC4Myk2Bv8HAA)

This can most definitely be shorter.

-4 bytes thanks to ovs.

Comment: You can use `⊃` (Pick) instead of indexing with brackets to save a byte. Then the inner dfn can be converted to a tacit function for 3 more bytes saved: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTflfrXF4@qPerZogctejjhnVGkBaByQS/ahvquOj3s1AdmztoRWPejqArFouLBrg6jQfdTVDtSN0YFihoQNWtgKmr2uRJkKxs8KjtgkKQJ56Rl5ZeWViVlVBaWpJUX5mWmF2RW5STnpycYo6VzBYlbpHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqiOhfQQLC4Myk2Bv8HAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, <s>147</s> <s>179</s> 151 Bytes

This method doesn't work for test cases containing ABCDEF due to the "g-97" statement.

```
x=[ord(i) for i in input()];c=chr
print("".join([c(g)*(not(c(g).isalpha())) or(c(x[g-97])*(g>97)or c(x[g-65]-32))for g in[ord(i)for i in input()]]))
```

There must be a shorter way  to do this using mapping, but I haven' quite figured the mapping function out yet. Golf'ed down from an original 180 just a shame its not quite a one liner.

```
x=[ord(i)for i in input()];y=[ord(i) for i in input()];t=""
for i in range(len(y)):
    g=y[i]
    if 122>g>97:t+=chr(x[g-97])
    else:t+=chr(g)*(not(90>g>65))or chr(x[g-65]-32)
print(t)
```

New method gets it to work with fewer bytes:

```
x=[ord(i)for i in input()];c=chr
print("".join([(c(x[g-97])if 123>g>96 else c(x[g-65]-32))if c(g).isalpha()else c(g)for g in[ord(i)for i in input()]]))
```

Movatica has a shorter [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235702/55243) using the string library. And using := I could reduced my answer to a one-liner at the expense of a few bytes

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 84 bytes

*Codebook needs to be a string too.*

```python
lambda a,s:s.translate(str.maketrans(ascii_letters,a+a.upper()))
from string import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLDoIwEADvfkXlQqsNF28m3v0DLiZmgRYq24fbRcWfr8TjTCaTVp5iOBV7uRUE3w0gQOdzbpggZAQ2MjM1HmbzNxJy79wdDbOhrOEIzZKSIamU2lmKXmy5C6NwPkXiQ0kbsbSynsLrvcLjm5btFJ19zh/f4djnodaiuhrEqEUbCYd9pVT5AQ)